# Problemas para descargar Excel con Jquery y .Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

Hola comunidad tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una app MVC donde quiero descagar un archivo excel de una grilla la cual esta hecha con Syncfusion.
Tengo los metodos programados ya que en otra parte de mi aplicacion funciona pero en esta nuevo me parece todo el tiempo la excepcion de nullreference. No estoy instanciando algo pero no me doy cuenta donde. De todo el analisis que hice me di cuenta que en el siguiente metodo de javascript con Jquery es donde se definen las propiedades

```js
    function toolBarClick(args) {
        alert("Metodo ToolBar");
        debugger;
        if (args.itemName.indexOf("Export") > -1) {
            this.model["numeroGranja"] = $("#numeroGranja").val();
            this.model["descripcionGranja"] = $("#descripcionGranja").val();
            this.model["estadoGranja"] = $("#estadoGranja").val();
            this.model["direccionGranja"] = $("#direccionGranja").val();
            this.model["localidadGranja"] = $("#localidadGranja").val();
            this.model["proveedoresGranja"] = $("#proveedoresGranja").val();
            this.model["nroCiclo"] = $("#nroCiclo").val();
            this.model["estadoCiclo"] = $("#estadoCiclo").val();
        }
    }
```

La grilla es la siguiente

```js
 @(Html.EJ().Grid<ProduccionAvicola.Models.FiltroGranjaModel>("Listado")
          .Datasource(ds => ds.Json((IEnumerable<object>)ViewBag.dataSource).UpdateURL("Edit").Adaptor(AdaptorType.RemoteSaveAdaptor))
          .EnableRowHover(true)
          .AllowSorting()
          .AllowPaging()
          .AllowResizing()
          .ClientSideEvents(c => { c.ActionBegin("ClientSidePaging"); c.ToolbarClick("toolBarClick"); })
          .PageSettings(p => p.CurrentPage((Session["paginaActual"] != null ? func.convert_to_int(Session["paginaActual"]) : 0)))
          .Locale("es-AR")
          .ToolbarSettings(toolbar => { toolbar.ShowToolbar().ToolbarItems(items => { items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.Search); items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.ExcelExport); }); })
          .AllowScrolling(true).ScrollSettings(x => x.Height(300))
          .Columns(col =>
          {
              col.Field("centro.numero").HeaderText("Número").Width(70).TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Add();
              col.Field("centro.descripcion").HeaderText("Descripción").Add();
              col.Field("estado.descripcion").HeaderText("Estado").Add();
              col.Field("centro.domicilio").HeaderText("Dirección").Add();
              col.Field("centro.localidad").HeaderText("Localidad").Add();
              col.Field("proveedores").HeaderText("Proveedor/es").Add();
              col.Field("numero_ciclo").HeaderText("Nro de Ciclo").Add();
              col.Field("ciclo.estado.descripcion").HeaderText("Estado de Ciclo").Add();
              col.HeaderText("").Template(true).TemplateID("#editTemplate").Width(40).TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Add();
              col.HeaderText("").Template(true).TemplateID("#detTemplate").Width(40).TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Add();
          }))
```

Luego en la parte del back tengo la siguiente clase en donde se deberia tomar las propiedades del metodo de javascript que muestro al principio de la pregunta

```html
  [DisplayName("NUMEROGRANJA")]
        public int numeroGranja { get; set; }

          [DisplayName("DESCRIPCIONGRANJA")]
        public string descripcionGranja { get; set; }

          [DisplayName("ESTADOGRANJA")]
        public string estadoGranja { get; set; }

          [DisplayName("DIRECCIONGRANJA")]
        public string direccionGranja { get; set; }

          [DisplayName("LOCALIDADGRANJA")]
        public string localidadGranja { get; set; }

          [DisplayName("PROVEEDORES")]
        public string proveedoresGranja { get; set; }

          [DisplayName("NROCICLO")]
        public int nroCiclo { get; set; }

          [DisplayName("ESTADOCICLO")]
        public string estadoCiclo { get; set; }
```

Paso el index (Controllers) donde supuestamente le estoy pasando esas propiedades a a vista

```html
   public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var model = new FiltroGranjaModel();
            try
            {
               
                //Si abro la pagina desde el menu principal borro la session que guarda la pagina actual seleccionada
                if (this.ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Segments[2] == "Menu")
                {
                    Session["paginaActual"] = null;
                }

                ProduccionAvicolaWs.ServiceClient srv = new ProduccionAvicolaWs.ServiceClient();
                //RetGranja resultado = srv.ObtenerListadoConInactivosGranja();
                RetGranja resultado = srv.obtenerListaGranjasTodosFormatoTipos("0");
                if (resultado.oError.Codigo > 0) throw new Exception(resultado.oError.Mensaje);
                var DataSource = resultado.listado;
                ViewBag.datasource = DataSource;
          

                if (Session["FiltrosGranja"] == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.existeSession = false;
                    ViewBag.paginaActual = 1;                              
                }
                else
                {
                        var sessionModel = (FiltroGranjaModel)Session["FiltrosGranja"];

                        model.numeroGranja = sessionModel.numeroGranja;
                        model.descripcionGranja = sessionModel.descripcionGranja;
                        model.estadoGranja = sessionModel.estadoGranja;
                        model.direccionGranja = sessionModel.direccionGranja;
                        model.localidadGranja = sessionModel.localidadGranja;
                        model.proveedoresGranja = sessionModel.proveedoresGranja;
                        model.nroCiclo = sessionModel.nroCiclo;
                        model.estadoCiclo = sessionModel.estadoCiclo;

                        ViewBag.existeSession = true;                                            
                }
           
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ee.Message);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Pero cada vez que me pongo a debugguear con el chrome el metodo del javascript esas variables me aparecen que no estan definidas , creo que ahi esta el problema por el cual no puedo descargar el excel. **Como puedo hacer para poder instanciar esas propiedades? en el index quizas? cuando le paso el model a la vista?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual es el error que te aparece en la consola y cual es la linea que dice la consola que tiene el error????

Comment: como llenas la grilla con ajax o en algún refresh???

Comment: realiza una búsqueda rápida en el código HTML Final a ver si encuentras `descripcionGranja`